# Как отключить авто выполнение команды в bash после копирования?

Tags: linux, bash

Когда вы копируете команду откуда либо в терминал - он без нажатия <kbd>Enter</kbd> ее выполняет. Как отключить эту функцию? В моем случае команда с опечаткой. Можно воспользоваться сторонним редактором, исправить опечатку и скопипастить команду в терминал. Но в 100 раз удобнее скопировать сразу в терминал и там-же исправить.
То же самое справедливо относительно последовательности команд.

Comment: «он без нажатия 'enter' ее выполняет» — неправда, не выполняет. Видимо, вы случайно копируете enter вместе с командой

Comment: Последовательность команд нужно копировать по одной или записывать в файл, потому что bash не текстовый редактор

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/237854/110559

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Там нет автоматического выполнения. Вы, вероятно, также копируете разрыв строки (или более) после команды.

Если вы вставляете команду с разрывом, оболочка (командная строка) считает, что вы нажали кнопку прерывания (к примеру <kbd>Enter</kbd>) самостоятельно.

Одно из реальных решений - открыть режим редактирования с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, а затем безопасно вставить ваш буфер обмена в выбранный вами редактор (к примеру Vim). После того, как вы закончите редактирование команды, сохраните и выйдите, и она запустится в командной строке. Это хорошая привычка для длинных или сложных команд, особенно при вставке хешей коммитов в команды `git`, и может помочь вам избежать некоторых страшных результатов в долгосрочной перспективе.

Также одно из решений, перед вставкой введите `#`, а затем вставьте свою строку. Она не будет выполнена, и вы можете удалить `#` и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>, когда изменения будут завершены.

[Источник](https://askubuntu.com/q/377259/772253)

Comment: ещё вроде бы некоторые менеджеры буфера обмена (в частности *parcellite* и его форк *clipit*) умеют вырезать пробелы (в начале и конце строки) и окончания строк. а некоторые, возможно, умеют и как-то заскриптовать обработку строк, попадающих в `xa_{primary,secondary,clipboard}`